# Jmeter error message while doing load test

Tags: jmeter

jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/10/27 13:01:24 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2015/10/27 13:01:35 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.template.TemplateManager: Reading templates from:C:\Users\A5WKVZZ\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\templates.xml

The above is the error log that appears when i ran the load test on my application .it stopped with warning and the log display is above .Can some body help me how to debug and run load test successfully?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: - Check the command prompt message and post it here. What is the load you are injecting?

Comment: Hi Naveen,do you mean the log for the test when you say command prompt? or anything else .load is 25 users

Comment: When you launch JMeter you can see a command prompt window as well. In that you can see the runtime error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any errors in the output, looks absolutely normal.

To debug your JMeter test:

1. Open JMeter GUI
2. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
3. Run your test with 1-2 users and 1-2 loops.
4. Inspect requests/responses details to ensure your script is doing what it needs to do. Check variable values (you may wish to use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) for it) if you correlated or parametrised something, make sure that you get logged in, there are no errors, etc.
5. Once you happy with your test behaviour increase virtual users number according to your load scenario and [run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/resultsfile.jtl
   ```

   You'll be seeing some diagnostic output and metrics like

   ```
   Creating summariser <summary>
   Created the tree successfully using example.jmx
   Starting the test @ Wed Oct 28 18:59:00 CET 2015 (1446055140362)
   Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
   summary +      1 in     1s =    1.0/s Avg:   318 Min:   318 Max:   318 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 47 Started: 47 Finished: 0
   summary +    749 in   2.4s =  312.5/s Avg:   160 Min:   134 Max:   483 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 50 Finished: 50
   summary =    750 in   3.4s =  219.6/s Avg:   160 Min:   134 Max:   483 Err:     0 (0.00%)
   Tidying up ...    @ Wed Oct 28 18:59:03 CET 2015 (1446055143862)
   ... end of run
   ```
6. Upon test completion open JMeter GUI again, add listener of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report), locate your .jtl results file using "Browse" button and analyse the output.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more debugging tips and gotchas.

Comment: Thread Name: Thread Group 1-85
Sample Start: 2015-10-29 13:48:27 CDT
Load time: 45
Connect Time: 38
Latency: 44
Size in bytes: 3772
Headers size in bytes: 352
Body size in bytes: 3420
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Comment: above is the error message i am getting for it .that says error500 .i tried with google and other sites with the same params its working fine but for our site its throwing this error.

Comment: See the full response in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and also check your site logs

Answer (score 0):

instead of web site URL i tried with Website IP and port number which i got from the site ip analyzer.It worked fine and got the test with out warning